How to apply to the Cauchy data to an equation?
$$u~x^2u_x+e^{-y}u_y+u^2=0,~~~~~~~u(x,0)=1$$
I have found the characteristics for this differential equation, but because both of the characteristics depend on u, u cannot be presented as an explicit function of x and y. Generally, is there any way of applying the Cauchy data that corresponds to the problems in which z can not be represented as an explicit function? What is the general way? Please solve the example if possible.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

I don't have access to the keyboard in which mathematical symbols are available

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Thanks. I'll apply that to my future posts.

There is no "general" method for just about ANYTHING in the field of PDEs.

You probably found the characteristics
$$
ue^{-1/x}=C_1\qquad\text{and}\qquad u=\frac{1}{C_2+e^{y}}, \tag{1}
$$
which combine to give the general solution
$$
u=\frac{1}{f(ue^{-1/x})+e^y}. \tag{2}
$$
Now, applying the boundary condition $u(x,0)=1$ to $(2)$, we obtain
$$
1=\frac{1}{f(e^{-1/x})+1} \implies f(e^{-1/x})=0 \implies f(s)=0\quad\text{if $s>0$.} \tag{3}
$$
It follows from $(2)$ and $(3)$ that
$$
u(x,y)=e^{-y}. \tag{4}
$$
